# Team City or TFS Team Build 2010?

Tags: tfs, build

We are currently in the process of setting up TFS for source control and a build server, to achieve automated build and deploy. But I'm stuck with the choosing between [Team City 7](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or TFS Team Build. The biggest pro with Team City are recommendation from others and when it comes to TFS Team Build its the fact that that [Chris O'Brien mentions it](http://www.slideshare.net/chrisobrien/automated-builds-and-ui-testing-in-sharepoint-2010-development-7671059) and has some good looking [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff622991.aspx).

We are a very small company if the size would matter, which I doubt. We mainly build SharePoint 2010 solutions.

Which should we choose, Team City or TFS Team Build 2010?

Which are the cons and pros of them?

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked in SE.

- [Team Foundation Build or TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2239249/495340)
- [TeamCity vs Team Build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851927/495340)

Comment: Only the last question, but not the first. The questions you are referring to don't explicit use TFS for source control and are developing SharePoint Solutions which could make a big difference on the choice i suppose. But I'm still very new to automated builds. I think I'll try the full MS approach to begin with.